# FX Foudry Gimp 2.10

Tags: gimp

I just updated to Gimp 2.10 and in FX Foundry, when applying the Photo-edge-mask-sharpen, I'm getting this error message:

```
Error while executing script-fu-edge-mask-sharpen:
Error: eval: unbound variable: WHITE-MASK
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Replace `WHITE-MASK` by `ADD-WHITE-MASK`.

You could be running a rather ancient version of the script, there are more recent versions around (but not all of them work with 2.10...). And in 2.10 there may be better ways to sharpen your image than scripts written for Gimp 2.6?